# About Transfer homomorphism from a group $G$ to its central subgroup $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, transfer-theory

I have a question about the following problem [Finite Group Theory, Martin Isaacs, Chapter 5]:

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H \subset Z(G)$ such that whose index in $G$ is $n$. Then using Transfer Evaluation Lemma we know that the map from $G$ to $H$ defined by $g \rightarrow g^n$ is a homomorphism. Well, I wonder how we can show that
if $|H|$ is coprime to $n$, then $G= H $ $\times$ $\ker(v)$ (i.e., G is direct product of $H$ and $ker(v)$), where $v$ is transfer map $G$ to $H$.
Actually it is obvious that the intersection of these two set is trivial since $|H|$ is coprime to $n$. How can I finish this problem ?

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$ and use `$\ker$` for $\ker$.

Comment: You should use quotes or blockquotes around text you've copied from another source, and cite sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $|H|$ is coprime to $n=[G:H]$, and the power map $v(g)= g^n$ is a homomorphism $G\to H$, then its restriction to $H$ is an automorphism because it has an inverse function ($g\mapsto g^{n^{-1}\bmod |H|}$). Therefore, the homomorphism $v$ must be onto. Suppose the kernel is $K$. You know $K\cap H$ is trivial because $v$ is bijective restricted to $H$. To show $G=KH$, suppose $g\in G$. If it were of the form $g=hk$, then we could apply $v$ to $g$ and get $v(h)$. So simply define $h=v|_H^{-1}(v(g))$ and $k=h^{-1}g$ to conclude. As $H$ is central, it is of course normal, so the conditions for $G=K\times H$ to be an internal direct product are met.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I get it now

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I get it now. Knowing that the function is surjective actually brings the result. I mean, using the fact $|HK| =  \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$, the result follows immediately since $|H \cap K|=1$ and  $ |H| = \frac{|G|}{|K|} $.